# jQuery .click() function with .attr()

Tags: jquery, click, attr

I'm trying to resize `div1` with the click function depending if `menuright` is visible.

I need help with the `$('a#hidediv').click(function ()`.

Right now, only the`a#showdiv` selector is functioning.

```
function mySetupFunction() {
    var one = $('#wrapper_content').width();
    var two = $('#menurigth').width();
    var remaining_width = parseInt($(window).width());

    $('#menurigth').hide();
    $('#div1').css('width', remaining_width);

    $('a#showdiv').click(function () {
        $('#menurigth').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
        $('#div1').css('width', remaining_width - two);
        $('a#showdiv').attr('id', 'hidediv')
    });

    $('a#hidediv').click(function () {
        $('#menurigth').hide();
        $('#div1').css('width', remaining_width);
        $('a#hidediv').attr('id', 'showdiv')
    });
}

$(document).ready(mySetupFunction);
$(window).resize(mySetupFunction);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the `id` on an element (which arguably isn't a good thing to do anyway, but that's beside the point), you don't change the event handlers that are bound to it.  The same click handler is still on that element.

Instead of binding to the elements, use event delegation and bind to a common parent.  Then you don't need to change the handler because the identity of the element will follow the click event.  Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#showdiv', function () {
    // your code
});

$(document).on('click', 'a#hidediv', function () {
    // your code
});
```

As the `id` changes, any time `document` receives the click event it will examine the *current* `id` of the element which invoked the event, so it will use the correct handler.

The main thing to learn here is that while the code *inside* the click handler runs any time the element is clicked, the code which *assigns* the click handler (`$('something').click(someFunction);`) runs only *once* when the page initially loads, and it assigns the handler to elements which match the selector *at that time* only.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the code like this,

```
var remaining_width = parseInt($(window).width());
function mySetupFunction() {
    remaining_width = parseInt($(window).width());
    var one = $('#wrapper_content').width();
    var two = $('#menurigth').width();

    $('#menurigth').hide();
    $('#div1').css('width', remaining_width);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#showdiv').click(function () {
        $('#menurigth').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
        $('#div1').css('width', remaining_width - two);
        $('a#showdiv').attr('id', 'hidediv')
    });

    $('a#hidediv').click(function () {
        $('#menurigth').hide();
        $('#div1').css('width', remaining_width);
        $('a#hidediv').attr('id', 'showdiv')
    });
    mySetupFunction();
});

$(window).resize(function () { mySetupFunction(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

With the input of both David and Annop's answers here is the fully working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var remaining_width = parseInt($(window).width());
    var one = $('#wrapper_content').width();
    var two = $('#menurigth').width();

function mySetupFunction() {
    $('#menurigth').hide();
    $('#div1').css('width', remaining_width);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'a#showchat', function () {
        $('#menurigth').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
        $('#div1').css('width', remaining_width - two);
        $('a#showchat').attr('id', 'hidechat')
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'a#hidechat', function () {
        $('#menurigth').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
        $('#div1').css('width', remaining_width);
        $('a#hidechat').attr('id', 'showchat')
    });
    mySetupFunction();
});

$(window).resize(function () { mySetupFunction(); });



</script>
```